# speed up folder reorg code

Tags: batch-file

I have some CMD code that Rojo and Magoo helped me write that runs against some XML files in a directory. The code grabs a date and time from the files in the file name and creates a year and month folder from it and then moves the files into them. The problem that I'm having is the folder itself contains 914,000 xml files and the script just can't handle it. I need something faster or a way to multithread the script. Another option I was considering is to move a few thousand files at a time and just run it on those from a temp directory and at the very end of the script move those folders into the production location. Here is the code and another script to create the XML files to test. The date isn't validated but for this exercise, they don't need to be. This will be running on a Microsoft Server 2012 R2 VM.
running Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz, 2000 Mhz, 1 Core(s), 1 Logical Processor(s) and 4 gigs of ram. I'm also including the Powershell and VbScript tags in case someone can offer any advise for writing the code in those languages.

**XML move script**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
Title Reorganizing XMLs - DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW!
color 0F
mode con: cols=100 lines=6
prompt $t $d$_$p$g

::Get start time
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
     set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

Echo Start time: %start%

set "sourcedir=C:\Temp\TestDummyFiles"
set "tempdir=C:\temp\xmlreorgtemp"

::call :Get1000Files %sourcedir% %tempdir% %total%

pushd %sourcedir%
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set "spaces=          "
SET /a filesMoved = 0, spinPos = 0, prev = 0

echo Moving XML Files...

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,7) do set "BS=!BS!!BS!"
for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do set "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

For %%A in (%sourcedir%\*.xml) do set /a cnt+=1
echo.
Echo Total XML files: %cnt%
echo.

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xml" ' ) DO (
        set /a filesmoved += 1 
        call :spinner !filesmoved! "%%~nxa"
)
call :spinner %filesMoved% Done.

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
     set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

echo End time: %end%
set /A elapsed=end-start

rem Show elapsed time:
set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%
echo Elapsed Time: %hh%:%mm%:%ss%
endlocal & echo;
exit /b 0

:Get1000Files
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir "%~1" /b /a-d *.xml') do (
    set /a cnt+=1 & move "%%~a" "%~2"
        if !cnt! EQU 1000 exit /b
)
exit /b

:spinner <filecount> <filename>
set /a spinPos += 1, spinPos %%= 4, ten = %~1 / 10 * 10
if "%~2"=="Done." set ten=%~1
set "str=[!spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!] %ten% files moved... [%~2]"
set "str=%str:~0,79%"
call :length len "%str%"
set /a diff = 79 - len
if %diff% gtr 0 set "str=%str%!spaces:~-%diff%!"
set /P "=!BS:~-79!%str%"<NUL
if "%~2" NEQ "Done." call :process %~2
exit /b 0

:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~2"=="" (set ret=0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~2"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
                set /a ret += %%I
                set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
        )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
exit /b 0

:process
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6delims=_" %%m IN ("%~1") DO SET "date1=%%m"&SET "date2=%%n"&SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 exit /b 1
If not exist .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2% MD .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%
MOVE %~1 .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%\ > nul
```

**And the script to create some dummy files**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d %~dp0
For /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') Do set "CR=%%a"
set fileSize=%~Z1
set /a cnt=0
echo Creating files. Please wait.&echo.
:loop
    if %cnt% GTR 5000 exit /b
    set /a cnt+=1
    set /p "=Creating %cnt% File(s)       !CR!"<nul:
    Call :random 2009 2015 yyyy
    call :random 1 12 mm
    call :random 1 31 dd
    if %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
    if %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%
    set /P "=0" > thisSize.txt < NUL
    (for /L %%i in (0,1,30) do (
         set /A "bit=(1<<%%i)&fileSize, fileSize&=~(1<<%%i)"
         if !bit! neq 0 type thisSize.txt
         if !fileSize! neq 0 type thisSize.txt >> thisSize.txt
    )) > IDABCDEFG001_STUFF_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_ABC_0_1234567890.xml
    del thisSize.txt
goto :loop 
exit /b

:random Min Max [RtnVar]
    @echo off & setlocal
    set /a rtn=%random% %% ((%~2)-(%~1)+1) + (%~1)
    (endlocal
        if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=%rtn%) else echo:%rtn%
    )
exit /b
```

The server has Powershell 4 on it.

Comment: ...And this is a batch script so how is powershell relevant?

Comment: Lots of people understand cmd script and powershell. I'm looking for a way to speed it up and powershell could be the answer. CMD script can be run on just about everything, so I wanted to get some feedback from all scripting environments. Everyone is able to run this code and see what it does and might have a solution in another scripting environment.

Comment: That maybe so, but StackOverflow is not a place for "can somebody rewrite my code for me in another language" requests. I'm unclear as to what you're actually asking for.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. I'm just looking for advice from others that have more experience in those other environments. This is actually a rather complicated CMD script and if I should re-write it in powershell, I can do that. I just want to know if it's possible to do it the same way, if it will actually speed up the processing.and how difficult it might be.

Comment: Yes, you could rewrite it in powershell and if you did rewrite it to use asynchronous background jobs then I suspect that it would speed the process up.

Comment: @EBGreen Thank you. I'm working on a powershell solution right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not powershell, but maybe this could do the work

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "xmlFolder=C:\Temp\TestDummyFiles"

    pushd "%xmlFolder%" && (
        for %%x in ("*_*_*.xml") do if exist "%%x" (
            for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nx") do if "%%c"=="" (set "fileDate=%%a") else (set "fileDate=%%b")
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!fileDate:~0,4! !fileDate:~4,2!") do (
                endlocal
                <nul set /p "=%%a\%%b : "
                md ".\%%a\%%b" 2>nul 
                move /y "*_%%a%%b??_*.xml" ".\%%a\%%b" 2>nul | find /v ":"
            )
        )
        popd
    )
```

There are three reasons for your code to be slow (appart from the fact that you are handling 914000 files):

1. There are 914000!! files
2. `call` usage is slow. 914000 * #calls for each file = very slow
3. 914000 status updates to console are slow
4. `for /f`

Yes, the `for /f` commands used in

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xml" ' ) DO (
for /f %%a in ('dir "%~1" /b /a-d *.xml') do (
```

have one problem because:

1. The `dir` command has to enumerate the 914000 files
2. The full list needs to be loaded into memory before starting to process it
3. The `for /f` command loads data into a buffer. When the buffer is full a new bigger (4KB increase in windows 7) buffer is created and data is copied from the old buffer to the new and this process is repeated until all the data has been retrieved. Each time the buffer is resized a larger memory copy operation needs to be done so the time needed to handle all the data increases exponentially.

This means

```
914000 files * ( 50 chars file name + CR LF ) = 47528000 characters
47528000 characters / 4KB buffer increase = 11603 redim operations
11603 redim operations = 1103170928640 bytes moved in memory copy operations
```

To handle all this, the proposed code will

1. Use a simple `for` to enumerate the files. The process starts on the first file being found and more search operations are done as the files are being iterated.
2. Instead of processing each file, all the files matching a date are moved in only one `move` operation.

Comment: This is perfect. I had to tweak it a little but with your excellent explanation and a tip I got from the dostips forum about a bug in `for` working with lots of files with long names, I was able to get all of them done overnight.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of files, then you may reorder its processing by the smallest number of groups. In your example code you create 5000 dummy files, but just in 6 years. The code below process files by year, then month:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "sourcedir=C:\Temp\TestDummyFiles"
pushd %sourcedir%

:nextYear
for %%a in (*.xml) do set "fileName=%%a" & goto break
:break
if not defined fileName goto :EOF

FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6 delims=_" %%m IN ("%fileName%") DO SET "date1=%%m" & SET "date2=%%n" & SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 exit /b 1

set "YYYY=%date1:~0,4%"
set "MM=100"
for /L %%m in (1,1,12) do (
    set /A MM+=1
    MD "%YYYY%\!MM:~1!" 2> NUL
    MOVE "*_%YYYY%!MM:~1!??_*.xml" "%YYYY%\!MM:~1!"
)
goto nextYear
```

In my opinion, you should started this topic with a description of the problem, like "I have 914,000 files with this format `IDABCDEFG001_STUFF_yyyymmdd_ABC_0_1234567890.xml` and I want to move they to folders with yyyy\mm structure". I really don't like to try to know the details of a problem reading code. I don't understand your code to get the date from the file name, so I just copied it...

Comment: You're right, I should have started the question that way. Thank you for your contribution. I really appreciate it.