# Create Batch file to delete folders that are a certain size

Tags: batch-file, size, directory, subdirectory

Looking to delete folders (subfolders as well) with a certain size (150mb).
The script I need would have to search multiple folders on different drives.
For example

delete folders under 150mb in E:temp/ , D:temp/ ,F:temp/

Thanks again for the help. I do not mean to waste your time, I did search everywhere and tried to make my own script but failed.

Comment: Show the script you have tried as sign of your own effort!

Comment: Dim objFD
Set objFD = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSelectedFolder = objFD.GetFolder("I:\Movies")
Set colSubfolders = objSelectedFolder.SubFolders
For Each objSubfolder In colSubfolders
If objSubfolder.Size < 150000000 Then
objSubfolder.Delete True
End If
Next

Comment: Folders don't have a size, the size reported is a cumulative value for all of the files contained within. For that reason you should reformulate your question to state exactly what it is you're intending to do when you append your code.

Comment: @Alex Please [edit] the code into your question. And please note that this is not batch but rather VBScript (I think).

Comment: yes, i know..Im very new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "150mb=157286400"
set "root_dir=E:\RootDir"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: recursive listing of the folders.
for /d /r  "%root_dir%\" %%# in ("*") do (
    rem echo %%~f#
    call :getSize %%#
    rem echo !size!
    if !size! equ !150mb! (
        echo rd /s /q "%%~f#"
    )
)



exit /b 0
:getSize    
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "target=%~1"
    if not defined target set "target=%cd%"

    set "size=0"
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in ('
        dir /a /s /w /-c "%target%"
        ^| findstr /b /l /c:"  "
    ') do if "%%b"=="" set "size=%%a"
    endlocal & (
        set size=%size%
    )
```

folder size function was shamelessly stolen [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514329/388389) . Mind that in pure batch you can get the size of file/folder only in bites - size is hardcoded at the beginning of the script but you can change it. On this line `echo rd "%%~f#"` the target folder is only echoed. You'll need to delete the `echo` to make it work.

Comment: thanks for your help npocmaka, I have to learn batch language badly..its so useful.